# Error when testing devise with omniauth and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I wrote this simple spec :

```
  it "redirects to dashboard upon login" do
      user = Factory(:user)
      visit "/users/sign_in
```

why am I getting this error?

```
Failure/Error: visit "/users/sign_in"
ActionView::Template::Error:
undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000102947cc8>:0x0000010293def8>
```

my spec_helper:

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {:user_info => {:name => "Joe Smith", :nickname => 'joesmith'}, :uid => '123456790'})
```

and devise spec helper:

```
module DeviseSpecHelper
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  end

  def login_with_oauth(service = :facebook)
    visit "/auth/#{service}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that very same error this evening. In my config/initializers/devise.rb file I had twitter and facebook set up for both dev and production, but I didn't have anything for test. After setting up some rubbish data for the testing environment, everything worked.

This is what I'm using in my devise.rb initializer, with real keys removed.

```
if Rails.env.production?
  config.omniauth :twitter, '7630184729174927491732', 'asdfia8akfuoiafo8uasdfjad;lsfjalsf'
  config.omniauth :facebook, '4759010482048301849821', 'asdfawer82395ahusfi8afier98hakfdha'
else
  config.omniauth :twitter, '1231231231231231231231', 'slakjsdflakhsldiuvalejhiubsdlfkjhasdfjasdl'
  config.omniauth :facebook, '123123123123123', 's4s4aeraw4rert4f4awefa34afw4a4f3'
end
```